# WordPress Menu highlight with pagination

Tags: wordpress, search, menu, pagination, highlight

I have a WordPress website with a menu similar to this one: [Yahoo news](http://uk.news.yahoo.com/), so basically:

- a horizontal menu with two levels, the first with main categories the second with sub-categories (in the "Home" menu item, the subcategory is the page "about us".
- I am using [the build-in](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) Menu of WordPress

The problem I have is with the pagination and also with the search form:

1. When I am in the Home Page and I
   click any pagination number, the
   subcategories of "Home" menu item
   disappears, and most importantly,
   **the "Home" menu item is no longer highlighted**.
2. When I search something, again the
   same issue, **the "Home" is no
   longer highlighted**, and there is
   no subcategory under "Home" menu
   item.

Comment: Can you post the urls you links generated and the url where it works?

How dou you highlight the home? Automatically, when there is no active category?

Comment: Sure, this is the first item in the home page:
`<ul id="menu" class="menu">
<li id="menu-item-1252" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-1252"><a href="#">Home</a><ul class="sub-menu"><li id="menu-item-1219" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-1219"><a href="#">About Us</a></li></ul></li>
</ul>`

Comment: And this is when I click in the pagination:
`<ul id="menu" class="menu">
<li id="menu-item-1252" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-home menu-item-1252"><a href="#">Home</a><ul class="sub-menu"><li id="menu-item-1219" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-1219"><a href="#">About Us</a></li></ul></li>
</ul>`

Comment: As you can see, there is no "current-menu-item" class when I click in the pagination. What shell I do to have, at least in the home.php template and while I search, the "home" link with "current-menu-item" class?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution:

1) Open header.php, and add this in the body tag:

```
<body<?php if ( is_home() || is_search() || is_404() )  { echo ' class="main"';} else { echo '';} ?>>
```

2) Add a class that target the home class, so:

```
body.main #main-menu ul li.menu-item-home a { 
    background: #313B47;
    color: white;
}
```

Now if I am in the home page, or in the search page, or 404 error page, WordPress adds class="main" to the body, so I can easily target the menu item which I want.

Comment: This doesn't help as the li class "current-menu-item" is lost on paging.   Has anybody found an answer for this yet?